# Service references management via PowerShell in VS

Tags: visual-studio-2010, wcf, powershell

Good morning

My company maintains a set of internal WCF services from various departments that we use throughout internal and external projects. The set of the services is fairly stable, meaning that there's a more or less constant number of services available. Each service has a test and a production address.

What I'd like to do is create a PowerShell script that would contain the list of all the services with their addresses, providing a single point of maintenance for such a list. The script would:

- allow to to add / refresh / remove services from the project
- have auto-completion for service names
- be distributed via NuGet (and perhaps included with a custom solution template)

Is this possible? Can I manage script references for a given project from the PS? Any pointers would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [`New-WebServiceProxy`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849841.aspx) command and this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1746980/399704